# getting multidimensional array data into object

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a PHP page that generates an array `$data` which is used in a `timesheet.php` file

In the array I have [booking] which I would like somehow to put into the place in `timesheet.php` indicated by ****BOOKING****

Here are the files:

Thanks

```
calendar_day.php

Array
(
    [HRU] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [booking] => 5
                    [start] => 10-00
                    [end] => 11-30
                )

        )

    [IHE] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [booking] => 8
                    [start] => 14-45
                    [end] => 18-30
                )

        )

)

**************************************************************************************
```

timesheet.php

```
<?php

class timesheet{

    /**
    * css ID for the timesheet
    */
    public $id;

    /**
    * By default, it's dark, without we can replace by 'white'
    */
    public $theme;

    /**
    * A string array of title for alpha section
    */
    public $alpha = array();

    /**
    * If alpha is a number and this number is not 0, we can substract this value
    */
    public $alpha_first;

    /**
    * The width of one Alpha section
    */
    public $oneAlpha ;

    /**
    * If omega value of the alpha not become to 1
    */
    public $omega_first;

    /**
    * The width of one Omega section
    */
    public $oneOmega;

    /**
    * original data
    */
    public $data = array();

    /**
    * Calculate datas for timesheet
    */
    private $ddata = array();

    /**
    * Calculate datas for mobile 
    */
    private $mdata = array();

    /**
    * The value {alpha}-{omega}] of the line
    */
    public $line;

    /**
    * The text value of the line
    */
    public $line_text;

    /**
    *
    */
    public $format = array();

    /**
    * Default css parameter for colors
    */
    public $colors = array('default', 'lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit');

    /**
    * HTML code to display
    */
    private $html;

    /**
    * Contructor
    * @param $alpha array : A list a title
    * @param $args array  : 
    *                   id : string
    *                   theme : null | white
    *                   alpha_first : int
    *                   omega_base : int
    *                   omega_first : int
    *                   line : null | {alpha}-{omega}
    *                   line_text : null | string
    *                   format : null | array
    *                   segment_des : string (text to display with sprintf() expression)
    *                   timesheet_format : string (date format)
    *                   date_format : string (date format)
    * @param $data array :
    *                   key => array(
    *                   array('start' => '{alpha}-{omega}','end' => '{alpha}-{omega}'),
    *                   ....
    *                   ),
    *                   ...
    */                  

    function __construct( $alpha, $args, $data = null){

        $default_args = array(
            'id'            => 'timesheet',
            'theme'         => null,
            'alpha_first'       => 1,
            'omega_base'        => 10,
            'omega_first'       => 1,
            'line'          => null,
            'line_text'         => null,
            'format'        => array(
                        'segment_des'       => '$s to $s',
                        'timesheet_format'  => null,
                        'date_format'       => null,
                        )
        );
        $args = array_merge( $default_args, $args );
        //print_r($args); //TCG

        $this->all_segment      = '';
        $this->alpha            = $alpha;
        $this->data             = $data;

        $this->id           = $args['id'];
        $this->theme            = $args['theme'];
        $this->alpha_first      = $args['alpha_first'];
        $this->omega_base       = $args['omega_base'];
        $this->omega_first      = $args['omega_first'];
        $this->line             = $args['line'];
        $this->line_text        = $args['line_text'];
        $this->format           = $args['format'];

        $this->oneAlpha = 100 / count($alpha);
        $this->oneOmega = $this->oneAlpha / $this->omega_base;

        $this->create_all_segments();
    }


    /**
    * Calculate the start value of a segment
    * @param int $alpha  The alpha value
    * @param int $omega The omega value
    * @return int Return start value of a segment
    */
    private function start_segment($alpha, $omega){
        $start_segment = ( ( ( ($alpha - $this->alpha_first + 1) - 1) * $this->oneAlpha ) + ( ( $omega - $this->omega_first)  * $this->oneOmega) );
        if( $start_segment < 0){
            $start_segment = 0;
        }
        return $start_segment;
    }

    /**
    * Calculate the end value of a segment
    * @param int $alpha  The alpha value
    * @param int $omega The omega value
    * @return int Return end value of a segment
    */
    private function end_segment($alpha, $omega){
        $end_segment = ( ( ( ($alpha - $this->alpha_first + 1) - 1) * $this->oneAlpha ) + ( ( $omega - $this->omega_first)  * $this->oneOmega) );
        if( $end_segment > 100){
            $end_segment = 100;
        }
        return $end_segment;
    }

    /**
    * Return the start value of the line
    * @return int Return the start value of the line
    */
    private function get_line_data(){
        $line = explode( "-", $this->line);
        return $this->start_segment( $line[0],  $line[1] );
    }

    /**
    * Display the Alpha section title
    */
    private function section_title(){
        foreach( $this->alpha as $alpha){
            echo '<section><div>'.$alpha.'</div></section>';
        }
    }

    /**
    * Calculate and create all segment and return an array of the data
    * @param string $level_key The id of a level (have 1 or more segment)
    * @param array $segment An array for a duration data for create one or more segment
    * @return string $return Return an array of segment(s) for a period / level
    */  
    private function calcul_timesheet($level_key, $segment){

        if($segment['start'][1] > ($this->omega_base + $this->omega_first)
                || $segment['end'][1] > ($this->omega_base + $this->omega_first) ) {
            var_dump('Omega ('.$segment['start'][1].' and '.$segment['end'][1].') is greater then omega_base value ('.$this->omega_base.') ! - key : ' . $level_key , $segment);
        }
        $start_segment = $this->start_segment($segment['start'][0], $segment['start'][1] );
        $end_segment = $this->end_segment($segment['end'][0], $segment['end'][1] );
        $return = array();
        /*
        * If curl and end < start then we create 2 segments
        * Else Just one
        */
        if($segment['end'][0] < $segment['start'][0]
                || ($segment['end'][0] == $segment['start'][0] && $segment['end'][1] < $segment['start'][1] )
        ){

            $segment['head_segment'] = true;
            $segment['marginleft'] = 0;
            $segment['width'] = $end_segment ;

            array_push( $return , $segment );

            $segment['head_segment'] = false;
            $segment['marginleft'] = $start_segment;
            $segment['width'] = 100 - $start_segment ;
        }
        else{
            $segment['head_segment'] = true;
            $segment['marginleft'] = $start_segment;
            $segment['width'] = $end_segment - $start_segment ;
        }
        array_push( $return , $segment );
        return $return;
    }

    /**
    * Initialize the calculation of all data before displaying (standard or mobile)
    */
    private function create_all_segments(){
        $i = 0;
        foreach($this->data as $level_key => $periods){
            $i++;
            $color = $this->colors[$i % 5];
            $segments = array();
            $m_periods =array();
            $m_period = array();
            foreach($periods as $period){

                // Simple array for mobile display
                $m_period = array( 
                    'title'=> $level_key,
                    'color' => $color,
                    'start' => explode( "-", $period['start']),
                    'end' =>  explode( "-", $period['end']),
                    );
                // Add period to an array
                array_push( $m_periods , $m_period);

                $tab = $this->calcul_timesheet($level_key, $m_period);
                foreach ($tab as $key => $value) {
                    $segments[] = $value;
                }
            }
            $this->ddata[$level_key] = $segments ;
            $this->mdata[$level_key] = $m_periods ;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Display a segment
    * @param string $key The id of a level
    * @param array $segment An array of segment's data
    * @param bool $head_level Can identify if the segment is at the beginning of the level
    * @return string $html The HTML code for a segment
    */
    private function get_segment($key, $segment, $head_level){
        ob_start();
        $displayDate = $this->get_format( $segment );
        ?>
        <div class="segment">
            <div style="margin-left: <?php echo $segment['marginleft']; ?>%;">
                <?php if( $head_level ) : ?><span class="label" >TCG <?php echo $segment['title']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
                <?php if( $segment['head_segment'] ) : ?><span class="date"><?php echo $displayDate ; ?></span><?php endif; ?>&nbsp;
            </div>
            <a href="TCGtest.php"><div style="margin-left: <?php echo $segment['marginleft']; ?>%; width: <?php echo $segment['width']; ?>%;position:relative;" class="bubble bubble-<?php echo $segment['color']; ?>" data-duration="6">****BOOKING HERE****</div></a>
        </div>
        <?php
        $html = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $html;
    }

    /**
    * Call for every level, every segment
    * @return string $html Return the HTML code for the timesheet
    */
    function get_display_data(){
        $html = '';
        foreach($this->ddata as $key => $level){
            $head_level = true;
            $html .= '<li>';
            foreach($level as $segment){
                    $html .= $this->get_segment($key, $segment, $head_level);
                    $head_level = false;
            }
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        return $html;
    }

    /**
    * Return the format information
    * @param array $segment Data of a segment
    * @param bool $mobile (default = false) If the information to displayed is for mobile or not
    * @return string $displayDate Return the String to display
    */
    function get_format( $segment, $mobile = false){
        $displayDate = '';

        if( !empty($this->format) 
            && !empty( $this->format['timesheet_format'] ) 
            && !empty( $this->format['date_format']) 
            ){
            $startdate = date($this->format['date_format'], strtotime( $segment['start'][0] .'-'. $segment['start'][1] ) );
            $enddate = date($this->format['date_format'], strtotime( $segment['end'][0] .'-'. $segment['end'][1] ) );
            $displayDate = sprintf( $this->format['segment_des'] , $startdate, $enddate);
        }
        else{
            $startA = $this->get_alpha_title( $segment['start'][0] );
            $endA = $this->get_alpha_title( $segment['end'][0] );

            // If data is is the same alpha, we don't repeat the information
            if( !$mobile && $segment['start'][0] == $segment['end'][0] ){
                $displayDate = $startA." ".$segment['start'][1].' to '. $segment['end'][1];
            }
            else{
                $displayDate = $startA  .'-'. $segment['start'][1]
                    .' to '. $endA  .'-'. $segment['end'][1];
            }
        }
        return $displayDate; 
    } 

    /**
    * Return the alpha title
    * @param integer $alphaN The alpha number
    * @return string $alpha Return the alpha title of a number, unless return the number
    */
    function get_alpha_title($alphaN){

        if( array_key_exists( (integer) $alphaN - $this->alpha_first, $this->alpha) ){
            return $this->alpha[ (integer) $alphaN - $this->alpha_first ] ;
        }
        else{
            return $alphaN;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Call for every level, every segment for mobile part
    * @return string $html Return the HTML code for the timesheet
    */
    function get_display_data_mobile(){
        $html = '';
        foreach($this->mdata as $key => $segments){
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= '<div class="label '.$segments[0]['color'].'" >'.$key.'</div><div class="dates '.$segments[0]['color'].'">';
            foreach($segments as $segment){
                    $html .= '<div class="date">'.$this->get_format( $segment, true ).'</div>';
            }
            $html .= '</div></li>';
        }
        return $html;       
    }

    /**
    * Display the HTML code of the timesheet
    */
    public function display(){
        $html = $this->get_display_data();
        $html_mobile = $this->get_display_data_mobile();
        ?>
        <style>
        #<?php echo $this->id; ?> div.scale section{
            width:<?php echo $this->oneAlpha; ?>%;
        }




        </style>

        <div class="timesheet color-scheme-default <?php echo $this->theme;?>" id="<?php echo $this->id; ?>">
            <!-- A line -->
            <div class="line">
                <section><div></div></section>
            </div>
            <!-- Section -->
            <div class="scale">
                <?php echo $this->section_title(); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end section -->

            <!-- data is the default and appear for reolution more than 500px -->
            <ul class="data">
                <?php echo $html; ?>
            </ul>
            <!-- mdata is for mobile and appear for reolution less than 500px -->
            <ul class="mdata">
                <?php echo $html_mobile;  ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php
    }
}// end class
?>
```

Comment: Please go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

It's too complicated, the information is not complete but, you can to try this:

Be sure your calendar_day.php return one array.

```
.
. CODE
.
$array = [ ... ];
.
. CODE
.
return $array;
```

On method getSement include your calendar_day.php

```
private function get_segment($key, $segment, $head_level){
    $aData = include('calendar_day.php');
```

Change the booking line ****BOOKING**** for this:

```
<?php echo $aData['HRU'][0]['booking']; ?>
```

Your data have some nodes but I printed only one.

I hope this help you.

Comment: hi thanks but that didnt work, the $data array ( incl the [booking] field ) goes into the $this->data array and must still be buried in there somewhere like the [start] and [end] fields. the question is how to find it in the mass of arrays along the way and to be able to display it at the ****BOOKING**** area? any help greatly appreciated. thanks